# Don't move Layout

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

I'm doing a vb.net button to run in ArcMap. the button is working, the problem is as I'm working in the layot when I press the button, change the layout coordinates and the map coordinates.

Is there a way that the layout view does not move and keeps the Coordinates (0,0)?

```
I leave the code:

MxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document

ActiveView = MxDoc.ActiveView

Dim x As Double = txtEast.Text

Dim y As Double = txtNorth.Text
                
Map.MapScale = 4000 'zoom to this scale

Envelope = ActiveView.Extent

,Create and Add the point coordinates
Point = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
Point.PutCoords(x, y)

'Envelope Position go to the middle of the point
Envelope.CenterAt(Point)


'Refresh View
 ActiveView.Extent = Envelope
 MxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()Map = MxDoc.FocusMap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting the ActiveView to MxDoc.ActiveView, which could be either an IMap or IPageLayout, set it to MxDoc.FocusMap

This code will move the map but not the layout

```
        Dim pMap As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IMap = My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap
        Dim pActiveView As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView = pMap
        Dim pEnvelope As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope = pActiveView.Extent
        Dim pPoint As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point

        pPoint.PutCoords(x, y)
        pEnvelope.CenterAt(pPoint)

        pActiveView.Extent = pEnvelope
        pMap.MapScale = 4000
        pActiveView.Refresh()
```